# NameError for filename?

Tags: python, list, io

I'm trying to write a program that assigns prices to a list, but I'm having trouble. I keep getting a NameError, that costlist is not defined. The program should ask for an input, append it to the list, and go through the whole list, then write it to the .txt file.

```
import os
def main():
    if os.path.exists("costlist.txt"):
        os.remove("costlist.txt")

print ("Assignment 6")
print ()
filename = input("Enter a file name, please. Or enter end to end.")
while filename != "end":
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        listie = file.readlines()
        for item in listie:
            print(item)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
            filename = input("Sorry, that file wasn't found. Try again?")
    if filename == "end":
        exit
file.close()
listie.sort()
file = open(filename, "w")
for item in listie:
   file.write(item.strip("\n"))
file.close()
for item in listie:
    cost = input(print( item + "should cost how much?"))
    try:
        float.cost
    except ValueError:
            print ("You entered an invalid float that can't convert string to float:" + cost)
            print ("Skipping to the next item after" + item)
    print (item + "has a cost of" + cost + "dollars")
    file = open(costlist.txt, "a")
    file.append(cost)
print ("Cost List")
file = open (costlist.txt, "r")
for item in file:
    print (item)
print ("Program End")
```

Comment: `costlist.txt` should have quotation marks around it (and no space before the left bracket in `open()`).

Comment: Thanks! That really helped. I'm down at the bottom now, working on the last bit to make it display the costs next to the items. i've edited my code, but I'm not sure how to display it in a comment...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enclose the file name by quotes.

Change `file = open(costlist.txt, "a")` to `file = open("costlist.txt", "a")`

And

`file = open (costlist.txt, "r")` to `file = open ("costlist.txt", "r")`